# How to get coverage report from a given package using nose2

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py, nose2

I would like to use [nose2](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose2) with coverage plugin to get the coverage of a Python package but I'm have a hard time configuring it to cover only the package I'm working on. The package is called `vimhdl` and the coverage section of my `unittest.cfg` looks like this:

```
[coverage]
coverage = vimhdl
```

With **nose2**, the result doesn't include all files from the package (maybe because of `Coverage.py warning: Module vimhdl was previously imported, but not measured.` message, but I don't know how to fix it).

Also, when opening the HTML report for a given file, statements such as  `import logging` and modules' doc strings are marked as not covered.

```
$ nose2 --with-coverage   -vvv
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.166s

OK
Coverage.py warning: Module vimhdl was previously imported, but not measured.
---------- coverage: platform linux2, python 2.7.10-final-0 ----------
Name                                  Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------
python/vimhdl/compilers/__init__.py      95     42    56%
python/vimhdl/compilers/ghdl.py          92     41    55%
python/vimhdl/config_parser.py           74     42    43%
python/vimhdl/project_builder.py        269    164    39%
python/vimhdl/source_file.py            126     51    60%
---------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                   656    340    48%
```

On the other hand, with **nosetests**, the result include all files as expected.

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage -vvv

Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------
vimhdl.py                          5      0   100%   
vimhdl/compilers.py               95     11    88%   46-47, 97, 106-108, 131-132, 149-150, 158
vimhdl/compilers/fallback.py      22      7    68%   31-32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47
vimhdl/compilers/ghdl.py          92     21    77%   91-94, 107-108, 151-172, 182
vimhdl/compilers/msim.py          94     72    23%   49, 52-69, 73-102, 113-124, 128-135, 138-151, 154-159, 163-169, 176-179, 185-190
vimhdl/compilers/xvhdl.py         61     46    25%   38-40, 44-51, 54-76, 87-98, 101-105, 110-126
vimhdl/config.py                  69     46    33%   21-22, 55-77, 81-83, 87-91, 95-105, 109-122, 126-135
vimhdl/config_parser.py           74     25    66%   33-34, 45-46, 50, 53-88, 117, 119, 124, 133
vimhdl/exceptions.py              12      4    67%   21, 24, 28, 31
vimhdl/project_builder.py        269    114    58%   23-24, 61-68, 92, 97, 102, 108, 115-121, 131-134, 139-146, 156, 169-170, 182-185, 205-219, 221, 237-273, 278-313, 332-336, 368-371, 373-376, 380-381, 384-385, 393-394, 400, 419-426, 430-431, 455-456, 462-476
vimhdl/source_file.py            126     25    80%   71, 86-87, 168, 172, 174, 176, 178, 197-198, 203-216, 219
vimhdl/static_check.py           104     88    15%   56-112, 119-132, 139-165, 169-188, 191-197, 200
vimhdl/utils.py                    8      5    38%   24-28
------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                           1031    464    55%
```

How do I configure `nose2` coverage plugin to cover only a given module?

The source code is on github at https://github.com/suoto/vim-hdl/tree/unstable if it helps.

Comment: I found a workaround that worked for a single test file by using the `coverage.py` API directly as show on [coverage.py](http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/coverage-4.0.3/api_coverage.html#the-coverage-class) docs. The problem is that it seems to work for only one file; repeating it on a different test source file does not generate a report with combined results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to control coverage.py is to use it to run your tests:

```
coverage run --source=vimhdl -m nose
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I'm still puzzled why using coverage plugin within nose2 doesn't works this way.